# Non-emterpreted calls during emscripten_sleep_with_yield()

Tags: emscripten

I have a C routine transpiled to Javascript via the [Emscripten emterpreter](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Emterpreter), that calls [`emscripten_sleep_with_yield()`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html?highlight=emscripten_sleep#c.emscripten_sleep_with_yield).  While it is yielding, I'd like to run some *non*-emterpreted C code in the asynchronous callbacks.  When I try to, there's an error message that says:

> **"This error happened during an emterpreter-async save or load of the stack. Was there non-emterpreted code on the stack during save (which is unallowed)?"**

In an abstract sense, I'm not sure why there would be any problem making calls to non-empterpreted code while the stack is loading or saving--it's not actually *on* the stack that's being asked to be preserved.

The motivation of this non-emterpreted code is to update some structures visible to the routine that yielded.  I've found it is *technically* possible for plain JavaScript in the callbacks to achieve influence by doing [`setValue()`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html?highlight=setvalue#interacting-with-code-access-memory) into the emscripten heap.  But doing the C manipulations via JavaScript is awkward, especially because many routines like `AllocateUTF8()` call `_malloc()` under the hood...and those have the same issue.

Here's a simple example that shows the problem.  Is there any way around this...e.g. to store the load/save state variables somewhere while the non-emterpreted call is made, then put them back??

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plain call during Emterpreter Stack Load</title>
    <script src="test.o.js"></script>
    <script>
      Module.onRuntimeInitialized = function() {
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("calling not_emterpreted()");
          _not_emterpreted();
        }, 0);
        _emterpreted_yielder();
        console.log("yielding...");
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void emterpreted_yielder() {
    while (1) {
        printf("emterpreted_yielder() sleeping...\n");
        emscripten_sleep_with_yield(1000);
    }
}

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void not_emterpreted() {
    printf("Entering not_emterpreted()\n");
}
```

Build with:

> emcc test.c -o test.o.js -s EMTERPRETIFY=1 -s EMTERPRETIFY_ASYNC=1 -s EMTERPRETIFY_BLACKLIST="['_not_emterpreted']"

Commenting out the call to `not_emterpreted()` in the html will lead to it doing the sleep loop one would expect.  And like I say, at that point you can instead do C influences as raw JavaScript instructions against the emterpreter heap.  But...isn't that what non-emterpreted emscripten C is??  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an overly-conservative error mechanism in emscripten.  In response to this question, the limitation has now been removed:

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/pull/6822